# Is it possible to cancel/write-off upcoming pledge payments?

Tags: pledges

We have had a few situations recently where we need to write off upcoming payments of a partially-fulfilled multi-installment pledge. The catch is that we want to preserve the record of the pledge but indicate we do not expect to receive the money. We need this for auditing purposes, to match our CiviCRM data to our accounting data.

For example, we had an grantor fund an employee for 2 years, paid quarterly. We had received the money for the first 5 installments, but now that employee is leaving, so we won't get the final three payments. I am looking for some way to mark the pledge closed, without deleting the payments or recording the forthcoming payments as completed. Is this even possible?

Thanks!